# Cannot execute parallel computation with functional API

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to implement the `countWords` function from the red book on the parallelism chapter. When I pass a thread pool to the function and I modify the function to print the thread counting the words, I can only see the main thread printed. This indicates me that I am not able to make this function execute in parallel.

What I currently have:

```
type Par[A] = ExecutorService => Future[A]

def asyncF[A, B](f: A => B): A => Par[B] = a => lazyUnit(f(a))

def lazyUnit[A](a: => A): Par[A] = fork(unit(a))

def unit[A](a: A): Par[A] = (_: ExecutorService) => UnitFuture(a)

def fork[A](a: => Par[A]): Par[A] = 
es => es.submit(new Callable[A] {
  def call = a(es).get
})

def countWords(l: List[String]): Par[Int] = map(sequence(l.map(asyncF {
println(Thread.currentThread())
s => s.split(" ").length
})))(_.sum)
```

When I run:

```
val listPar = List("ab cd", "hg ks", "lh ks", "lh hs")

val es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)

val counts = countWords(listPar)(es)

println(counts.get(100, SECONDS))
```

I get:

```
Thread[main,5,main]
8
```

I would expect to see a thread printed per each element of the list (as there are four elements and a thread pool of size 4) however I can only see the main thread printed.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: As you put it in your code example, the `println` expression should not have been placed within the `countWords` function. By placing the expression as you did within the `call` method in `fork`, I can see all threads involved in this computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to start with one piece of advice when asking questions - you should always provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code doesn't compile; for example, I have no idea where `UnitFuture` comes from, I have no idea what's the implementation of `sequence` that you're using etc.

Here is a snippet that works with standard Scala. First, the explanation:

Method `countWords` takes a list of strings to count, and also two services - one for handling Java Futures on different threads, and one for handling Scala Futures on different threads. Scala one is derived from Java one via `ExecutionContext.fromExecutor` method.

Why both Java and Scala? Well, I wanted to preserve Java because that's how you initially wrote your code, but I don't know how to `sequence` a Java Future. So what I did was:

- for each substring:

  - fork a Java Future task
  - turn it into a Scala Future
- sequence the obtained list of Scala Futures

In case you're not familiar with implicits, you will (if you intend to work with Scala). Here I used the execution context implicitly because it removes a lot of boilerplate - this way I don't have to explicitly pass it when converting to Scala future, when mapping / sequencing etc.

And now the code itself:

```
import java.util.concurrent.{Callable, ExecutorService, Executors}
import java.util.concurrent.{Future => JFuture}

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

def scalaFromJavaFuture[A](
  javaFuture: JFuture[A]
)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[A] =
  Future { javaFuture.get }(ec)

def fork(s: String)(es: ExecutorService): java.util.concurrent.Future[Int] =
  es.submit(new Callable[Int] {
    def call = {
      println(s"Thread: ${Thread.currentThread()}, processing string: $s")
      s.split(" ").size
    }
  })

def countWords(l: List[String])(es: ExecutorService)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Int] = {
  val listOfFutures = l.map(elem => scalaFromJavaFuture(fork(elem)(es)))
  Future.sequence(listOfFutures).map(_.sum)
}

val listPar = List("ab cd", "hg ks", "lh ks", "lh hs")

val es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(es)

val counts = countWords(listPar)(es)

counts.onComplete(println)
```

Example output:

> Thread: Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main], processing string: ab cd
>   Thread: Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main], processing string: hg ks
>   Thread: Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main], processing string: lh ks
>   Thread: Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main], processing string: lh hs
>   Success(8)

Note that it's up to execution context to determine the threads. Run it a couple of times and you will see for yourself - you might end up with e.g. only two threads being used:

> Thread: Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main], processing string: ab cd
>   Thread: Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main], processing string: hg ks
>   Thread: Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main], processing string: lh ks
>   Thread: Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main], processing string: lh hs
>   Success(8)